# Combining/separating Pig UDF returns

Tags: apache-pig

Suppose a Pig UDF creates two different types of data records.

How can a Pig script process the returned list of combined Tuples from this UDF in two separate ways?

For example:

```
public Tuple exec (Tuple input)  // input ignored in UDF for simplicity
   {
   Tuple t = TupleFactory.getInstance ().newTuple ();
   if (Math.random () < 0.5)
      t.append ("less than half");
   else
      t.append (new Date ());
   return t;
   }
```

The Pig script should do something like:

```
register ...
define myUDF ...
data = load ...;
combinedList = foreach data generate myUDF (data);

stringList = filter combinedList by $0 instanceof java.lang.String; // ??
dateList = filter combinedLists by $0 instanceof java.util.Date; //??

store stringList into ... ;
store dateList into ... ;
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here.

1. Under no circumstances should you **ever** return different data types from your UDF. This is against the principle of least surprise and a couple of other things. If you want to indicate an invalid value, returning `null` or some invalid constant would be much more appropriate.
2. What you're trying to do is not done with multiple filters, there is the `SPLIT` operation for that. Although your example of using `instanceof` within Pig is wrong, the basic usage would be like `SPLIT combinedList INTO stringList IF $0 instanceof String, dateList IF $0 instanceof Date`.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  Suppose the UDF is redesigned to always append both a String and a Date to the returned Tuple (to avoid the "least surprise" concern).  How can the Pig Latin script be written to split out each list?

Comment: @user2250400 See point Nr. 2 in my answer -- use `SPLIT` with a condition. Read up more on it [in the Pig docs](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/basic.html#SPLIT). The basic idea would then be like `SPLIT c INTO stringlist IF res.$0 IS NOT NULL, datelist IF res.$1 IS NOT NULL`. However, I'd still suggest that you return either a `Date` or `null` from your UDF and then handle the invalid records later in MR, instead of the way you're trying to do it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using multiple `FILTER`s instead of `SPLIT`; in fact, Pig internally rewrites the `SPLIT` using multiple `FILTER`s.  See "Non-Linear Data Flows" in http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/advanced_pig_latin.html